# Get more than 2 aggregate results in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I have an indexed grid and am using the following in field calculator to get a grid reference for each grid a road intersects.

It works fine except when the line intersects more than 2 grid cells. Is there a way to write this so that it finds all grid intersects?

```
aggregate(
layer:= 'Grid',
aggregate:='concatenate',
expression:=Name,
concatenator:=', ',
filter:= intersects(
geometry(@parent),$geometry)
)
```

So the road in the image below should have Grid_Ref = AC13,AD13,AE13,AE14,AE15
[image]

Also is it possible virtually merge the dataset this is being run on so that it treats all segments that have the same road name as one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a virtual layer to achieve this with a SELECT statement like this one:

```
select st_union(geometry), name from roads_l group by name
```

This will 'merge' or better union the geometries of the layer roads_l with the same name in a virtual layer. Be aware, that if your layer contains a lot of objects, the virtual layer will slow down QGIS on every action like zoom/pan and so on.

Comment: Thanks but how about the main question of getting more than 2 grid references when it intersects more than 2 grids?

Comment: first make the virtual layer, then make your aggregate function on that virtual layer

Comment: That worked but I'm confused on why it worked? I tried to first dissolve the data by road name and then run the same aggregate formula and it doesn't work. What's different in working via the virtual layer?

Comment: theoretically it should be the same.